# Generate Oomph product setup from existing Eclipse installation

Tags: eclipse, oomph

I would like to create an Oomph product setup file based off of an existing Eclipse installation. Is there a way to generate a setup file as a sort of snapshot of a current installation?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out - it is not possible, at least not with one click. Here is what I did:

1. Create new project.setup
2. Check which update sites are configured in eclipse and create repositories under the p2 Task:

code:

```
<setupTask xsi:type="setup.p2:P2Task">
   <repository url="http://download.oracle.com/otn_software/oepe/12.2.1.6/oxygen/repository/"/>
```

3. Use the repository explorer to copy+paste some plugins that are installed and will be needed into the p2 task.
   That's it, now you have a new eclipse installation.
4. Configure projects